# Moving a RigidBody2D a specific amount of units

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

In my 2D side-scrolling game I move my character using the built-in physics engine by manipulating the `rigidbody.velocity`.

I would like to add some sort of dodge (roll) ability, where the character moves 3 units in its direction.

Here is the code I used:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) ) {
        Vector2 pos = rb.position;
        pos.x -= 5;
        rb.MovePosition (pos);
    }
}
```

This method works but the character kind of jumps to the position rather than moving to it (Lerping?) and also doesn't detect collisions despite the body type being dynamic.

Then I tried this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) {
    rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-50, 0));
}
```

I found the `AddForce` way isn't accurate at all.

Is there a proper way of doing this?

Comment: If you want to apply the force immediatly instead of gradually, you should use `rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-50, 0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change the Transform.pos inside Vector2.Lerp to make it look smooth? (Sorry, not enough experience with 2D in unity.)

Comment: I would like to move the character using velocity or force in order for it to detect collisions. And I think whatever the method is it could be applied for both 2D and 3D.

Answer (score 0):

Just increase rigibody.velocity for a set time. Your chararter object could then play a fitting aniamtion. If The player should not be able to cancle midrole jsut block the controls for that time.

Comment: This would take a lot of trial and error in order to determine how long and at what speed the character will move exactly 3 units. And If I decided later to change the amount from 3 units to 4 for example, it would be the same thing again.

Comment: Instead you could tack the distance traveld and keep the velocity constant till 3 units are passed. Then you only have to change the velocity till the role has the desiered speed :)